# How to validate JSON and show positions of any errors?

Tags: json, validation, go

I want to parse and validate (custom) JSON configuration files within Go. I would like to be able to parse the file into a struct and validate that:

1. no unexpected keys are present in the JSON file (in particular to detect typos)
2. certain keys are present and have non-empty values

In case the validation fails (or in case of a syntax error), I want to print an error message to the user that explains as detailed as possible where in the file the error happened (e.g. by stating the line number if possible).

The JSON parser built into Go seems to just silently ignore unexpected keys. I also tried using jsonpb (Protobuf) to deserialize the JSON, which returns an error in case of an unexpected key, but does not report the position.

To check for non-empty values, I could use an existing validation library, but I haven't seen any that reports detailed error messages. Alternatively, I could write custom code that validates the data returned by the built-in JSON parser, but it would be nice if there was a generic way.

Is there a simple way to get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [JSON schema](http://json-schema.org/)?

> JSON Schema describes your JSON data format.

I believe it is in Draft stage, but a lot of languages have validation libraries. Here's a Go implementation:

- https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonschema

Comment: Thanks. Yes I tried the implementation you linked. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to return the error position in case the validation fails.

Comment: I haven't tried the library myself. Maybe error position is something which could be added to it?

Comment: I looked a bit more into xeipuuv's gojsonschema. It can print information about the error position:
`fmt.Printf("- %s: %s\n", error.Context().String(), error)`.

This prints: 
`- (root).0: name: name is required`

Comment: Is there a way to detect unexpected fields using JSON Schemas?

Comment: I wrote a lot of the error handling in that library. You can define a schema with `additionalProperties` set to `false` and then look for the `additional_property_not_allowed` error type from the library. You can extract the field name from `ResultError.Field()` to get the name of the unexpected field.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `encoding/json` JSON Decoder and force errors when unexpected keys are found. It won't tell you the line number, but it's a start and you don't require any external package.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type MyType struct {
    ExpectedKey string `json:"expected_key"`
}

func main() {
    jsonBytes := []byte(`{"expected_key":"a", "unexpected_key":"b"}`)

    var typePlaceholder MyType

    // Create JSON decoder
    dec := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewReader(jsonBytes))

    // Force errors when unexpected keys are present
    dec.DisallowUnknownFields()

    if err := dec.Decode(&typePlaceholder); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

}
```

You can see that working in playground [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Oki7a1b_VM5)